# php/mysql INSERT INTO SET

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting `INSERT INTO SET` to work. I know its not conventional and VALUE is suppose to be used. But the SET command does visually make inserting into fields easier. The first insert works with no problem but `m_pos` does not post when I add the `$pos1` variable. If I remove the `$pos1` variable and input a string like "1" it works.

```
$pos1 = "1";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO social_info SET 
    m_id = '.intval($id).', 
    m_pos = '.$pos1.'"
);
```

Comment: What's the value of $pos1 ?

Comment: @RayViljoen right above the query I have `$pos1 = "1";`

Comment: :o My bad.. Looks like @seanbreeden has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $pos1 = "1";
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO social_info SET 
 m_id = '.intval($id).', 
 m_pos = '.$pos1.'"
 );
```

You have messed your syntax up a bit.  Should be:

```
$pos1 = "1";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO social_info SET 
m_id = ".intval($id).", 
m_pos = ".$pos1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@@seanbreeden is correct you missing the "", it should be something like this.

$pos1 = "1";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO social_info SET m_id = '".intval($id)."', m_pos = '".$pos1.'");

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When answering a question, please make sure that your answer is constructive regarding the question. Your answer simply rephrases the already accepted answer (and therefore is in my opinion not really constructive).

Comment: Since you reference the accepted answer, you know that the answer has been given. How does your answer add value?